# Merge (join) data frames - too many rows in result

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames(df1 and df2). I want to join them using merge function.

df1 has 3903 rows and df2 has 351 rows.

I want to left join df2 to df1 by a common column(column1). I am using merge function.

My code is like below:

```
dfjoin<-merge(df1,df2, by="column1",all.x=TRUE)
```

So I expect dfjoin has 3903 rows equal to rows of df1. However it returns 4010 rows.

Why does it return more rows than expected. I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This may be because the values in column1 from df2 are not a 1-1 mapping. Meaning a single value in column1 may be related to more than one value in column2. You can check this by using `table(df2$column1)`. If you find a value from column1 with a count > 1 then this is the reason.

Comment: Also I would like to recommend an alternative if you are more comfortable with sql there is a very nice library called `sqldf` which allows you to use sql like queries on your data frames!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be because the values in column1 from df2 are not a 1-1 mapping. Meaning a single value in column1 may be related to more than one value in column2. You can check this by using `table(df2$column1)`. If you find a value from column1 with a count > 1 then this is the reason.

Also I would like to recommend an alternative if you are more comfortable with sql there is a very nice library called `sqldf` which allows you to use sql like queries on your data frames!

Comment: Thanks a lt RDizzl3. As you said the tables were not one to one mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without seeing an example of your problem, but usually the syntax is:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by.all="name_of_column_in_common", all.x=T)
```

However, if the columns you are matching on have duplicated values, r will match all possible combinations. So,

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("a","a","b","c"), x1=rnorm(4))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c("a","a","b"), x2=rnorm(3))
df <- merge(df1, df2, by.all="id", all.x=T)
```

Will give you a df of dimensions 6 by 3, as each "a" in df2 has been matched to each "a" in df1, 2 by 2 for 4 permutations.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your second data frame is unique on the join column(s), you can use my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) (a wrapper around *`dplyr`*'s join functions) which will give you an explicit error if it's not the case.

Current situation :

```
df1 <- data.frame(column1 = c("a","b","b"), X = 1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(column1 = c("a","b"), Y = 4:5)
df3 <- data.frame(column1 = c("a","a","b"), Y = 4:6)

merge(df1,df2, by="column1",all.x=TRUE)
#   column1 X Y
# 1       a 1 4
# 2       b 2 5
# 3       b 3 5

merge(df1,df3, by="column1",all.x=TRUE)
#   column1 X Y
# 1       a 1 4
# 2       a 1 5
# 3       b 2 6
# 4       b 3 6
```

Some values were duplicated by mistake.

Using [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
safe_left_join(df1, df2, check= "V")
#   column1 X Y
# 1       a 1 4
# 2       b 2 5
# 3       b 3 5

safe_left_join(df1, df3, check= "V")
# Error: y is not unique on column1
# Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

`check = "V"` controls that the join columns are unique on the right hand side (`check = "U"` like **U**nique checks that they are unique on the left hand side, `"V"` is the next letter in the alphabet).