# Cannot allocate vector of <large> size Gb while performing inner_join in R

Tags: r, memory-management, inner-join

**Solution**

After reading the comments posted by
@Jon Spring, @Sweep Dodo and @Gregor Thomas carefully, I realized the issue was a large number of duplicate keys in the **chr** column. I simply created new columns by pasting chr:start together for both tables so there would be a lot fewer duplicate entries. After this the `inner_join` completes in a couple of seconds.

**Issue**

Running 64-bit R 4.1.2 on Windows 11.

I have two tables

Table 1:

| chr | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chr7 | 117120017 | 117120018 |
| chr7 | 117120018 | 117120019 |
| chr7 | 117120019 | 117120020 |
| chr7 | 117120020 | 117120021 |
| chr7 | 117120021 | 117120022 |
| chr7 | 117120022 | 117120023 |

188700 rows x 3 columns

Table 2:

| chr | starthg38 | endhg38 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chr7 | 117479963 | 117479964 |
| chr7 | 117479964 | 117479965 |
| chr7 | 117479965 | 117479966 |
| chr7 | 117479966 | 117479967 |
| chr7 | 117479967 | 117479968 |
| chr7 | 117479968 | 117479969 |

188700 rows x 3 columns

I try performing simple inner join,

```
new_table <- inner_join(table1, table2, by = c("chr" = "chr"))
```

and get the following error

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 132.7 Gb

Based on solutions suggested here
[R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

I tried,

```
gc()
```

and

```
memory.size(max = TRUE)
```

but neither of these solutions worked. More importantly, I'm trying to understand **why** R thinks allocating 132.7 Gb is necessary for such a small join operation.

Comment: I'm guessing from the `start****` and `end****` columns that you are going to follow up with some sort of filtering operation, perhaps to find overlaps within matching `chr` values? If so, it will be more memory efficient and faster to do a non-equi join using `data.table` or `sqldf` then doing a big join where every `ch7` value in each table is matched with all the same values in the other, effectively squaring the number of rows per `chr7` value and making potentially a very large table. In the extreme case, if every row was `chr7`, your cartesian join would have 35 billion rows.

Comment: A vector of 132.7 GB is indeed a large vector. In my experience, even an 8GB vector cannot be created (on my lap top. Depends on RAM). As @JonSpring pointed out. Your data have many repeating values in join keys e.g. `ch7`. Now think of an extreme example where both your dfs have `ch7` in both join keys only. This boils down to a cross join where the number of rows resulted is `nrow(df1) * nrow(df2)`. In your case 188,700^2 = 35,607,690,000
Thus, not as small a join as it seemed.

Comment: Suggested duplicates [Merge (join) data frames - too many rows in result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35956108/903061), or [INNER JOIN in MySQL returns multiple entries of the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50750381/903061)